# How to make \@abspage@last work as the number of total pages

Tags: page-numbering

By the following codes, I expect to typeset a pdf file of two pages. In the frist page, I want to print `(1)(2)`.

But it does not work. I guess this is because of the wrong use of the LaTeX macro `\@abspage@last`, or wrong use of compiler option argument. Anyone has ideas to make it work?

Codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{\@abspage@last}
\makeatother
%\newcommand{\lastpagenumberA}{\PreviousTotalPages}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpagenumber}{(\i)}
%\rule{\numexpr 4/\lastpagenumberA\relax in}{5pt}
\clearpage\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `.aux` file doesn't exist, `\@abspage@last` is set to 1073741823 and of course you don't want to produce that many pages.

So, let's try and “fix” by telling LaTeX that if `\@abspage@last` equals `\maxdimen` we set `\lastpagenumber` to, say, zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{%
  \ifnum\@abspage@last=\maxdimen
    \expandafter 0%
  \else
    \expandafter\@abspage@last
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpagenumber}{(\i)}

\clearpage

\mbox{LAST}

\end{document}
```

Now, if the `.aux` file doesn't exist (or, for some reason, it doesn't set a value for `\@abspage@last`), you get two pages. The first page has “(1)(0)” (because of how `\foreach` works) and the second one has “LAST”.

OK, now the `.aux` file exists and contains

```
\gdef \@abspage@last{2}
```

We run again LaTeX to get “(1)(2)” in the first page and “LAST” in the second one.

Perhaps even better, as it avoids one expansion step when using `\lastpagenumber`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifnum\@abspage@last=\maxdimen
    \def\lastpagenumber{0}%
  \else
    \let\lastpagenumber\@abspage@last
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpagenumber}{(\i)}

\clearpage

\mbox{LAST}

\end{document}
```

I do `\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{}` for safety: if some package you load defines `\lastpagenumber`, you get an error and you know you cannot use this command.

Next, after the `.aux` file is read in (provided it exists), we check whether `\@abspage@last` is `\maxdimen`; in this case we define `\lastpagenumber` to expand to `0`, otherwise we make it equal to `\@abspage@last`.

Comment: I don't understand what ```\expandafter``` does here, can you explain it to me, thanks!

Comment: @ljguo I want to remove `\else` or `\fi`. That's a common trick in TeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107753/4427

Comment: Absolutely excellent answer - even I understand it. +1.

Comment: @egreg This is the most detail, wonderful explanation I have ever seen! Thank you so much! And, (1) `\def\lastpagenumber{0}`, So the value `0` is not important, it can be any integer number? (2) Should it be `\global\def\lastpagenumber{0}`, as it is in the scope of `AtBeginDocument`? (3) Does `avoids one expansion` refer to `\let\lastpagenumber\@abspage@last`? (4) Is it possible to  `\expandafter\let\lastpage\@abspage@last  \fi', if so, is this a good idea?

Comment: @lyl (1) Yes, you can set it to whatever integer value you like. (2) When the code in `\AtBeginDocument` is executed it's not in any scope. (3) Yes. (4) That's completely wrong code.

Comment: @egreg (2) If I put the above`\AtBeginDocument{...} into a macro(named \getlastpagenumber`, for exmple, should `\global\def` be used? (4) I mean similar like `\expandafter (\let\lastpage\@abspage@last) \fi' (I know this is wrong syntax), I use it to express my idea. Is it possible?

Comment: @lyl Sorry, but I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: @egreg if only aux was the problem, I tried `\IfFileExists{\jobname .aux}{\makeatletter\let\lastpagenumber\@abspage@last\makeatother}{}` and expected it to work, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: I think this is related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576082/174620

Comment: @Niranjan The existence of the `.aux` file doesn't guarantee that `\@abspage@last` has a sensible value.

Comment: @egreg Oh, okay. So the `.aux` approach would be bad in any case. The problem that I was facing was because of the strange working of `\IfFileExists` which I have reported: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1132

Comment: @egreg (4) I mean how to expand `\fi` first, then expand `\let\lastpage\@abspage@last`?

Answer (score 1):

you can say:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_new:N \l_lastpage_file 
\file_if_exist:nTF{\c_sys_jobname_str.page}
{
  \file_input:n{\c_sys_jobname_str.page}
}
{
  % \cs_set_eq:NN \lastpage \relax
  \cs_set:Npn \lastpage {1}
}
\AtEndDocument{
\iow_open:Nn \l_lastpage_file{\c_sys_jobname_str.page}
\iow_now:Nx \l_lastpage_file 
{
  \cs_set:Npn \exp_not:N \lastpage 
  {
    \thepage
  }
}
\iow_close:N \l_lastpage_file 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpage}{(\i)}
\rule{\numexpr 4/\lastpage\relax in}{5pt}

\newpage
test

\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpage}{(\i)}
\rule{\numexpr 4/\lastpage\relax in}{5pt}
\newpage
test

\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpage}{(\i)}
\rule{\numexpr 4/\lastpage\relax in}{5pt}
\end{document}
```

---

This also works, but it still needs to be compiled twice!

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ifnum\@abspage@last > 1000
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{1}
\else
\newcommand{\lastpagenumber}{\@abspage@last}
\fi
\makeatother
\foreach \i in {1,...,\lastpagenumber}{(\i)}
AA
%\rule{\numexpr 4/\lastpagenumberA\relax in}{5pt}
\clearpage\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ljguo. This solution also needs run twice -- the first run gives unexpected typeset(from `\cs_set:Npn \lastpage {1}` ?), and the second gives the expect typeset. during the first run in which calculation of the number of total pages is performed, if the value of `\lastpage`(now is an uncorrect value) influences the ultimate number of physical  pages,  then the second run of the codes may lead to a wrong typeset.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be run twice, the first one generates ```\jobname.page```, the second time reads the file, since the first ```\lastpage``` has not been imported, you can only use ```\cs_set:Npn \lastpage { 1 }``` to avoid ```Undefined control sequence.```